# FM Modulation Index and Frequency trippler

Tags: signal-analysis, modulation, homework

Suppose I have an FM signal with modulation index mf which is passed through a frequency tripler, then what will be the modulation index of output waveform ?.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: How does the frequency tripler work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The modulation index is the peak frequency deviation divided by the maximum frequency of the baseband signal. Take a look at the formula for the FM signal and see what happens if the frequency is tripled. How does the peak frequency deviation change? How does the maximum frequency of the baseband signal change? I'm sure you can take it from here.

If not, please edit your question to let us know where you get stuck and ask a specific question (not just "please solve my problem").